# Why only beautify two peyoth?

Tags: minhag, payot-sideburns, beard

The explanation I have always been given for long, curled peyoth among those that have the minhag, is that it is for beautifying the misswah of peyoth. However, there are seven peyoth, only two of which are the sideburns.

There are the peyoth of the head, which are beautified.

> One is liable for each corner. Therefore, a person who shaves both his temples - even if he were to do so simultaneously and had received only a single warning – is [liable for] two measures of lashes. [Rambam Hil. A"Z 12](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1412.htm):1

But there are also five peyoth on the beard which are not.

> The beard has five "corners": the upper and lower cheek on both the right and left sides, and the hair on the chin. One is [liable for] lashes for the removal of each "corner." A person who removes them all at the same time is [liable for] five measures of lashes. Rambam Hil. A"Z 12:7

Given all the peyoth are misswoth, why do only the peyoth of the head deserve beautification? Why not the peyoth of the beard?

Comment: I don't really follow why the two different Mitzvot should be the same. Do you also want to beautify Peot of the field? Why should the fact that both relate to corners be relevant?

Comment: Citing sources for this explanation that you've "always heard" would improve this post dramatically. It's hard for anyone to figure out why a certain practice applies in specific circumstances without details of it, let alone if it even exists or you are reporting it correctly.

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, why not beautify the peyoth of the field as a way of honoring the poor? But the peyoth of the beard and head are more closely related. They are both given in the same verse, have similar halakhic requirements and punishments, and both relate to the growth of hair. I know the beautification of one does not necessarily follow from the other, but why was it decided to beautify one as opposed to the other?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's what I was taught. Googling around got a couple of sources but nothing that cites anything traditional or particularly old. Just the opinions of a couple contemporary rabbis. Perhaps a better question would be why grow and curl the peyos of the head at all?

Comment: I read somewhere, I forget where, that this started simply for practical reasons. The *lo ta'aseh* itself is the prohibition against cutting the *pe'ot* down to their roots (i.e. *hashchata*). But the *mehadrim* let them grow (and didn't even shorten them, which is allowed). When there are only sideburns that grow to the sides, it looks weird, so people started "beautifying" them, and it became a sign of a Jewish man in certain countries. A growing beard, however, doesn't need this beautification, as it was a standard for others as well.

Comment: @ShamanSTK Indeed asking about something you don't know first before using it as a premise in another question seems very prudent.

Comment: You're asking about "long, curled peyoth". I'm not sure about curled, but there certainly is a practice of keeping one's _peos hazakan_ long.

Comment: Re the above comments (not mine) -- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37316

Comment: ShamanSTK, do you want this question closed while you sort out its details? It's easy to reopen and meanwhile won't get answers that don't really address your concerns.

Comment: @msh210 the answers in your link don't explain why head peyoth would be long as opposed to the beard. I don't think it needs to be closed. Cauthon was the only one to give an answer and it certainly understood the question. Any feedback for clarifying would be appreciated as I'm still very new to this site.

Comment: why do you assume the payos of the beard are not beautified? Wouldn't not shaving fit this description?

Comment: @Dude not shaving is the halakha. Beatification is in addition to this. I don't shave my sideburns, but I don't beautify them by growing them out or curling them.

Comment: @ShamanSTK sorry I should have been more specific. I meant not trimming at all. having a full beard

Comment: how are you defining "hidur"?